# How to convert string array into a string without escaping any character?

Tags: vb.net, string

I need to convert a string array into a very long string with following requirement:

1. can not using any character escaping
2. can not using XML
3. can not using single character as separator (e.g. comma or space as separator)

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?  (The "why" would be very helpful here.)  Why are each of your restrictions necessary?  Do you need to be able to re-create the Array from the String?  If so, what you're asking is pretty much impossible, as  you've eliminated both encoding (could be classified as character escaping) and field delimited options.

Comment: Sample input and desired output would help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to join the string array into a long string, use the String.Join method:

```
Dim veryLongString As String = String.Join("", arrayOfStrings)
```